How could I grow this array via a function?
Being a Fortran noob (my apologies...), I ran across how to grow an array doing this:
program grow_an_array
    implicit none
    integer ,dimension(:),allocatable :: num1,num2
    integer :: n


    allocate(num1(10))
    do n=1,50 !note that n goes beyond the bounds of array num1
        if(n>size(num1,dim=1))call growarray()
        num1(n)=n
    end do
    print *

contains

subroutine growarray()
    implicit none

    allocate(num2(size(num1,dim=1)+1))
    num2(1:size(num1))= num1(1:size(num1,dim=1))
    call move_alloc(num2,num1)


end subroutine

end program

Both arrays are global so everything works, but I'd love to see an example of this same thing, but using a function call.
For the main logic...
array of original size called num1
function call to growarray(num1)
num1 is now the enlarged array ready for additional storage, unbeknownst to the main logic.
I don't know if you're supposed to pass a pointer to num1 into the function, and return a new pointer value for num1 and assign it to num1, or whatever.... I'm still trying to learn passing arrays to functions, in general.

Do not think about passing any pointers. There are no pointers in your code. You have allocatable arrays, not pointer arrays. Fortran is not C. Thinking about arrays as pointers is not helpful - especially not when starting to learn the language - despite allocatable arrays actually being implemented similar to pointers somewhere under the hood. They behave quite differently.

Growing an array by 1 every time is highly inefficient. There is continuous memory allocation/deallocation. Maybe you should look at the strategy that c++ uses for its dynamically-resizable std::vector.

Your approach is ok, and can be generalized with a routine that takes the array as an argument. The point is that in the routine, the array has to be declared with the allocatable attribute to make it work:
subroutine growarray(arr,newsize)
    implicit none
    integer, allocatable, intent(inout) :: arr(:)
    integer, intent(in) :: newsize

    integer, allocatable :: tmp(:)

    allocate( tmp(newsize) )
    tmp(1:size(arr))= arr(:)
    call move_alloc(tmp,arr)
end subroutine

Note that as mentioned in the comments, you should not think about Fortran arrays as classical pointers, they are specific objects.

And because of the allocatable attribute of the dummy argument (amongst other reasons) there must be an interface in scope at the calling point.
